# Appfog Django admin css missing

Tags: python, django, appfog

I'm using http://appfog.com I have DEBUG = True and ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/' 
The css for the admin is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django only serves static files if DEBUG=True **and** it is running the development server.

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development):

> This view is automatically enabled and will serve your static files at STATIC_URL when you use the built-in runserver management command
>   [...]
>   To enable this view if you are using some other server for local development, you'll add a couple of lines to your URLconf. The first line goes at the top of the file, and the last line at the bottom.

Example:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using dbieber's [Django template for appfog](https://github.com/dbieber/django-appfog-helloworld) this is the approach that worked for me:

1. Create a directory for static files in your project directory, then set up a URL to have the appfog server serve these files:

   ```
   cd <project>
   mkdir static
   ```
2. In urls.py, make sure the urlpattern is set to include static files (this is already there if you use the template):

   ```
   urlpatterns += patterns('', 
    ...
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 
        'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT), 
    )
   ```
3. Collect all static files into the static directory

   ```
   python manage.py collectstatic
   ```
4. Deploy to appfog

   ```
   af update <appname>
   ```